# Mysql Count(*) as Total WHERE Total?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT
  Id, QId, UName, Ans, Date, COUNT(*) * 10 as Total
FROM
  question
WHERE
  COUNT(*)
DESC
GROUP BY
  UName
```

doesn't work :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you wanted to filter groups. Use `HAVING COUNT(*)` instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Id, QId, UName, Ans, Date, Count(*) * 10 as Total
FROM question
GROUP BY UName
HAVING Count(*)
```

If you what to sort groups by number of elements then use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT Id, QId, UName, Ans, Date, Count(*) * 10 as Total
FROM question
GROUP BY UName
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```

Comment: WHERE filters on rows, HAVING filters groups