# Group By and Limiting the output in mySql

Tags: mysql

I am having a difficult time with the syntax.  I know where the error is but cant get the line correct.

Lets say in trying to count food groups and I want to see the detailed count of food groups.

This works great:

```
SELECT FoodGroup, Count(*) as mycount
FROM Food
Group By FoodGroup
```

I get a nice output

```
Vegies 190
Spices  64
breads  16
```

But I wish to limit my output to those with 50 or more items

```
SELECT FoodGroup, Count(*) as mycount
FROM Food
Where mycount > 49   <--this line in the issue
Group By FoodGroup
```

What should the WHERE clause Look Like?

Comment: You are looking for the having keyword instead of the where clause. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246086/mysql-count-as-total-where-total Having works on groups while where works on rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT FoodGroup, Count(*) as mycount
FROM Food
Group By FoodGroup
Having mycount > 49
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE` as follow

```
SELECT FoodGroup, Count(*) as my_count
FROM Food  
GROUP BY FoodGroup
HAVING my_count > 49
```